# .net maui CarouselView autoplay loop

Tags: carousel, maui

im using maui CarouselView control, but it is not autoplay,
how can i make it auto play, and change the slides after one or two seconds if possible.
the current behavior is should swipe manual to move to the next slid inside the Carousel.

Comment: You need to use a Timer

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: **Define Your Model**

First, create a data model for the items you want to display in the CarouselView. Here's an example model with an ImageUrl property:

```
public class CarouselItem
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2: **Set Up the XAML**

In your XAML file, define the CarouselView and its ItemTemplate. Bind the ItemTemplate to display images using the ImageUrl from your model.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
             x:Class="YourNamespace.YourPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <CarouselView x:Name="carouselView">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Step 3: **Implement Autoplay in Code-Behind**

In your code-behind, initialize a DispatcherTimer to change the carousel's position at specified intervals. This example uses a 1-second interval.

```
public partial class YourPage : ContentPage
{
    private IDispatcherTimer Timer = Application.Current.Dispatcher.CreateTimer();

    public YourPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var items = new List<CarouselItem>
        {
            new CarouselItem { ImageUrl = "bar_chart.png" },
            new CarouselItem { ImageUrl = "dashboard.png" },
            new CarouselItem { ImageUrl = "setting.png" },
        };

        carouselView.ItemsSource = items;

        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        Timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    }

    private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (carouselView.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            var itemCount = carouselView.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count();
            if (itemCount > 0)
            {
                var nextPosition = (carouselView.Position + 1) % itemCount;
                carouselView.Position = nextPosition; // Move to the next item
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        Timer.Stop();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Timer.Start();
    }
}
```

To change the autoplay interval for the **CarouselView**, you need to adjust the Interval property of the **DispatcherTimer** in your code-behind file. The **Interval** property determines how often the **Tick** event is fired, which in turn updates the position of the CarouselView to achieve the autoplay effect.